# is there a "this" like statement on transact SQL?

Tags: sql-server

i'm working on a database made from a log, and i need to check if the register on the log file isn't already in my DB.
this is my log file:

| Date | time | Order | Quantity | Lenght | Outputs | StartDate | StartTime | EndDate | EndTime | TotalTime | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04 | 17:56:00.000 | AZUL | 9 | 16 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 17:57:00.000 | AZUL | 9 | 16 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 17:58:00.000 | AZUL | 9 | 16 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 18:00:00.000 | GRIS | 5 | 52 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 18:01:00.000 | GRIS | 5 | 52 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 18:02:00.000 | GRIS | 5 | 52 | 0 | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 01/01/97 | 12:00 AM | 0 | 0 |

I managed to filter the registers with a view, however i want to transfer that to a proper table in order to be able to manipulate that data, i tried with a Trigger, the problem is: how can i check if the register isn't already there

this is the filtered pseudo-table

| EndDate | EndTime | StartDate | StartTime | Position | Order | Lenght | Quantity | Oututs | linealMeters | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-11 | 12:18:00.000 | 2022-02-04 | 18:05:00.000 | 0 | ROJO | 52 | 42 | 78 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-02-04 | 17:58:00.000 | 2022-02-04 | 12:13:00.000 | 0 | VERDE | 98 | 32 | 15 | 0 | 1 |

there are some discrepancy, because the view takes all registers form the log "Rojo" it's my current order, while "Verde" it's the last one.
the divice i'm working on, uses autogenerated SQL statements to retrive data only, thats why i'm using the log file.

In fact i am using 3 pseudo-tables: one for completed orders(0), one for current orders(1), and one for the queue(2)

Comment: Use an `EXISTS`?

Comment: Can you give an example of the trigger you'd like to write, and the statement that would trigger it?

Comment: already tried, but how can i tell if an especific register is already on the table, if i am transfering the full view table?

Comment: [Edit] your question, @HirokiSh . The comments are not for information that should be in the question.

Comment: Though that DDL statement looks "fishy". Where is your reference to the `inserted` pseudo table?

Comment: it is from the LOG_Pedidos table, wich is the log table, it selects 1 of the registers using a DISTINCT, then i add the minimum date and the maximum date from the log

Comment: As Larnu says, please [edit] the question to include the best SQL you've come up with so far. Comments are meant to be disposable, so don't support proper formatting. Also, try to keep the question simple - if there are details which are true of your application but not relevant to the problem, come up with a simplified scenario and test that (see the [help] page titled "[mre]").